# Ethernet not working. Says cable unplugged on Ubuntu Gnome 14.10

Tags: networking, 14.10, ethernet

When I go into the network settings in Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 (Which I heard is now a official flavour of Ubuntu) it usually says it's connected but at 10Mbs which is extremely slow and barely scratches the surface of my 30Mbs speed. I know my Ethernet card is capable of connecting up to 1Gbs! When I turn off the Ethernet and turn it back on, it just puts it back at 10Mbs! Once I unplug the cable and put it back in, it says "Cable Unplugged" when it's plugged in! My Ethernet card is a Realtek 8111 I think. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0m4XGHEL) for what is says for.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just turned off the computer, removed the battery and left it for 15 minutes. Then it jumped back to 1Gbps.

Answer (score 1):

10Mbps is standard fall-back mode for when things are not quite clicking as they should.
Causes could be either:

- NIC of the laptop
- network cable used is defective or with strange wiring or not crimped well
- port on the switch you're connecting is bad

It would be best if you can try plugging the laptop with same cable on a known good switch port and see what it gives you, then replace the cable, until you find root cause.

Comment: I tried a different cable with the system already booted and it says "Cable Unplugged". I will try the Ethernet on my Windows dual boot and see if I get the same thing with the other cable and the new cable. I will also restart the system to see if it switches to 1Gbs on the different cable when I boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: After rebooting the computer with the new cable and running a speed test on Ubuntu I got 9Mbps for download. So basically 10Mbps cap again. On Windows everything is flipped upside down so I get my usual 1Gbps cap and 30Mbps download on speedtest. What is going on????